# Connecting a Tun to a socket

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tun

I want to connect a Tun to a socket so that whatever data is stored in the Tun file will then end up being pushed out to a socket which will receive the data. I am struggling with the higher level conceptual understanding of how I am supposed to connect the socket and the Tun. Does the Tun get a dedicated socket that then communicates with another socket (the receive socket)? Or does the Tun directly communicate with the receive socket? Or am I way off all together? Thanks!

Comment: What is a `Tun` file?

Comment: the file located at /dev/net/tun that gets written to/read from

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem, you should be able to write an application that connects to the tun device and also maintains another network socket. You will need some sort of multiplexing such as epoll or select. But, basically, whenever you see data on the tun interface, you can receive the data into a buffer and then provide this buffer (with the correct number of received octets) to the send call of the other socket. Typically you use such a setup when you insert some custom header or something to e.g., implement a custom VPN solution.